# Limiting object access to only one thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, object

I've just gotten into multi-threading with Java and I've come to realize that several approaches I've taken to object access and modification don't work as reliably in a multi-threaded environment.

For example I've got a key wrapped up like this:

```
class KeyBean {
    private String key; // The key to be retrieved goes here
    private long timestamp; // UNIX-based timestamp

    public String getKey() {
         // is key available? - yes
             // update timestamp
             // return key;
         // is key available - no
             // return null
    }

    public Boolean isKeyAvailable() {
        // xxx seconds have passed
            // return true
        // else
            // return false
    }
```

Then I have a managing class that stores all the possible key objects in a list

```
class KeyManager {
    private List<String> keys; // The key to be retrieved goes here

    public String getNextAvailableKey() {
         // iterate list until available key is found
         // return key;
    }
}
```

The idea is the managing object would be requested for a key. When a request is received it'd iterate through a list of keys (not a long list.. 20 at maximum).

Once an available key was found it'd be returned to the object making the request.

On a single thread this worked just fine, but in an environment where I'm multi-threading there are instances where two threads iterating through that key list may access a key object at the same time resulting in multiple uses of the key which isn't intended.

So I'm just wondering what's the best approach to 'lock' access to a object the instant it is accessed so only one thread can use it. The ideal solution would allow other threads to pass over that object and continue searching for other keys and once that particular key has been used it's released back into the pool for the next thread to access.

Unfortunately I'm not exactly sure what terminology is used for the solution in this case so I'm asking in hopes I can get some direction.

Comment: I think a simple `synchronized` to the `getNextAvailableKey` may be enough

Comment: @ZhaoGang Assuming the logic is changed so getting the key removes it too.

Comment: Sounds like you need to totally rethink what you're doing. E.g. a queue might be a better choice, when keys are added to the queue as they become available.

Comment: I think the question requires more context. Are you concerned only about multi-thread iteration over the list ? Or is it about having a key available to one thread only ?

Comment: I looked into using the `synchronized` keyword and it seems to do the trick. I haven't delved too far in how it impacts performance since only one thread can iterate the list at a time, but it seems to be minimal since the lists are short. I'll continue exploring this. However, Andreas has an good point. I didn't consider using queues for available keys. I'll keep that in mind as I work with this. Thanks everyone

Comment: Since `getKey()` updates timestamp and `iskeyAvailable()` reads that timestamp both methods should be marked as `synchronized` to establish **happens before** relationship between write to timestamp and read from that timestamp